# Как перечислить все экземпляры класса?

Tags: java

Новичок в Java. Хочу понять как правильно, но в то же время по простому перечислить все экземпляры класса и вывести их названия. Для чего это нужно не спрашивайте, сам не знаю, просто мои размышления довели до вопроса: "а можно ли вообще это сделать?". Если это запрещено концепцией ООП в Java, то хотелось бы соответствующего комментария. В BlueJ всегда выводятся все созданные экземпляры классов, значит как то можно! Как посчитать экземпляры понятно: Нужно в конструкторе переменную статическую увеличивать на 1. А вот как красиво записать в Список имена экземпляров? Или тупо есть какой нибудь мне неизветный простой механизм их перечислить?

Comment: а что такое имя экземляра? Название переменной? Хеш-код объёета (@#####) или что?

Comment: Название переменной. Например я хочу обойти все экземпляры класса и дернуть у них какой-нибудь метод.

Comment: t1 = new Test(); // t1 - это имя экземпляра класса

Comment: угу а ещё есть `int a = new Test().getInt();` и что тогда? Все названия вы никак не узнаете, хеш коды ещё может быть...

Comment: Извините я не понимаю. Не понимаю зачем рефлексия и хеш-коды. Слишком мал ум еще. Просто я взял книжку по Java и дочитал до ООП. Там есть понятие класса (делаются в отдельном файле) и понятие экземпляра класса (это когда выполняется программа и их может быть несколько). Например я описал класс Car и насоздавал его экземпляров: car1, car2 и car3. Какой мне сделать код, чтоб он выдал: "car1, car2, car3"? И где его сделать: в конструкторе класса car или в другом месте. Я пока вижу такое решение: создать массив, в который запоминать созданные car1, car2, car3.

Comment: значит пока считайте что это нельзя сделать. в Java есть костыли на основе рефлексии и даже прямого чтения стуктуры  аллоцированной памяти, но пока вы не сформулируете какой от этого прикладной смысл то считайте что так нельзя. Если вам это понадобилось то 99% серьёзный косяк архитектуры. И кстати, без использования GC вы это не сделаете, т.к. не знаете когда будет уничтожен объект (в Java delete нету). А если с ним то это уже другой уровень (возможно `unsafe` ) что против методологии...

Comment: @user2931517 
ответ на " Какой мне сделать код, чтоб он выдал: "car1, car2, car3"?"

вот у тебя есть объект стакан{
цвет, 
размер, 
вес}
Стакан стаканБелогоЦвета = new Стакан(белый, 10 на 10, 10 кг);
говоришь, стаканБелогоЦвета.получитьЦвет() и получаешь какого цвета стакан твой 
можно сделать стаканБелогоЦвета.toString() и получишь это 
Стакан[цвет=белый, развер=10 на 10, вес= 10кг]

Comment: Как то странно, что я не могу посчитать сколько создал объектов и перечислить их без костылей. Я стараюсь мыслить как автор любой книги для на чинающих по Java. Типа чтоб было почти как в реальном мире, создаем объекты, описываем объект в классе. Но оказывается не так то просто их перечислить.

Comment: Как же сборщик мусора уничтожит их, если мне ,например, надо запросить через метод каждого объекта "ученика" сколько ему лет?

Comment: Я понимаю что я могу выполнить car1.toString() но если я не знаю что это car1, я должен перечислить все "кары" для начала.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы порекомендовал продолжать чтение, и не отвлекаться на всякую бесполезную ерунду :-) В мире Java есть много куда более интересных вещей :-)

Имена переменных, объявленных в каком-то методе, Вы не получите. Переменная - всего лишь указатель на объект. И говорить, в контексте привязки объекта к имени переменной некорректно. (кстати, понятия `"Имя экземпляра класса"` в Java не существует)

То есть, для такого случая:

```
public void main(String args[]) {
  Test t1 = new Test();
  ...
}
```

определить имя переменной `t1` невозможно.

**Если же говорить о списке экземпляров определенного класса, а не о их "именах", то тут уже другой разговор.**

В английской версии StackOverflow уже ответили на этот вопрос:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947122/is-there-a-simple-way-of-obtaining-all-object-instances-of-a-specific-class-in-j Тут автор советует смотреть исходники IDE Eclipse использующие **Java Debug Wire Protocol** и обращает наше внимание на **Java Debug Interface**.

Если же нас интересует конкретный класс, то можно воспользоваться таким решением:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071065/getting-all-instances-of-a-class

правда, я бы упростил код так:

```
public class Test {
   public static List<java.lang.ref.WeakReference<Test>> instances = new ArrayList<>();

   public Test() {
      instances.add(new java.lang.ref.WeakReference<Test>(this));
   }
}
```

То есть, теперь, обратившись `Test.instances` мы получим список слабых ссылок на все экземпляры данного класса. Почему `WeakReference` !? Чтобы не мешать сборщику мусора их убирать. Если бы мы сделали просто список объектов, то сборщик мусора бы никогда не убрал эти объекты, даже, если они уже не используются в коде.

Answer (score 1):

через reflection выполнить Instanceof , если совпадает, то ++
например, вот так ты можешь получить все поля класса

```
/*
Generate column list from fields of class type
 */
public String getColumns(Class classType){
    String result = "";
    Field[] classFields = classType.getFields();
    for(int i=0; i< classFields.length-1; i++)
        result += classFields[i].getName() + ", ";
    result += classFields[classFields.length-1].getName();
    return result;
}


public void fieldValue(Class classType){
        Object typeOfFieldsClass = classType.newInstance();
        Field[] classFields = typeOfFieldsClass.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field field : classFields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.get(someObject)
  // и вот тут получаешь значение
```

Comment: а как через рефлексию проверять все поля? Одно поле я понимаю, все поля класса тоже его могу представить, но как вообще все? (Включая возможно переменные в анонимных классах или локальные или анонимные переменные)...

Comment: @pavel, поправил ответ

Comment: подождём автора, я понял вопрос чуть по другому.

Comment: сразу предупреждаю автор будет долго вкуривать.

Comment: @user2931517, вроде все по-человечески написал. но если что - спрашивай